# Is it possible to separate a function without passing many parameters? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, properties, react-props

I add a component to the page and pass the value parameter to it. before rendering, a validation function is run in the component to find the mismatch.

```
export default function Example({value}) {

    const [error,setError] = useState(false)
    let min = 5
    let max = 10

    validation()

    function validation() {
        if(value<min) return  setError(true)
        if(value>max) return  setError(true)
    }

    return(
        <>
             <div>{value}</div>
            {error && <div>ERROR</div>}
        </>
    )

}
```

I want to move the validation to a separate file. But then I have to pass all the parameters to this function. In a real project, this is a big function, with many options. This method seems to me very inconvenient and hard to maintain.

`validation(min,max,value,setError)`

Is there a way to separate a function without passing dozens of parameters to it?

Comment: You can have `min` and `max` hardcoded inside the function or in the global scope, but if you want them to be configurable then yes you should pass them in. Not really different from the `validation` function being declared inside the component.

Comment: I wouldn't pass `setError` but rather use a return value.

Comment: Can you show your real code? If you really need a big function because it has to validate the entire intermingled state, then yes you'll have to pass the entire state (preferably as one big object). Nothing wrong with that. But ideally you'd validate only parts of the state in multiple separate validation functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract `validation` function's logic in a separate custom hook and call it at the beginning when component code starts executing. This hook's sole responsibility would be to decide value of `error` and based on `validation` function's logic and return it to the component.

Refer [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook) for more information.